# 'more' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: postgresql, heroku, psql, heroku-cli

I'm a windows user and trying to connect my db in Heroku.

so after entering heroku pg:psql, I had the access to my database.

I created a table without any errors. So now I want to check my table data.

But after running

```
kqhwudhkquwd=> select * from users;
'more' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

I get this error. It seems the SELECT command doesnt work. Pls help thanks

Comment: I would recommend using pgadmin to connect to your db and check data, etc.

Answer (score 6):

`more` is unix [pager](http://pager:%20https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144016/what-is-a-pager) - it is used, when the result cannot be printed on one screen. If it is not available, then your `PATH` configuration is not correct. There are two solution:

- fix your system configuration - Right Click on)  My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced tab -> Environment Variable -> set the PATH in system variables.
  Add these to the `PATH` variable : `%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\system32;%PROGRAMFILES%\PostgreSQL\9.x\bin`
  Based on mailing list [reply](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CANnQH_j0bbC8SPtiCT8pf9R7QyvuVmOFF7UYtxLMhKy-x_cShg%40mail.gmail.com).
- disable pager

  ```
  \pset pager off
  select * from users;
  ```

Comment: Hmm, on my Windows 10 computer, `where more` returns `C:\Windows\System32\more.com` so `more` is available in Windows by default.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you have true, so the error message is strange - but the workaround is same - disable pager. I found this issue in mailing list - so I fixed my reply.

Comment: I'm new to PostgreSQL so I don't know the implications of this but disabling pager fixed this same error for me. Thank you!